# returning collection (list) in c# as Json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetUserData")]
public ActionResult GetUserData()
{
    using (var ctx = new myEntities())
    {
        ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var user = ctx.Users.Include("UserRoles").FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == 4);

        ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        return Json(new
        {
            Email = user.Email,
            Roles = user.UserRoles
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The post is done via jQuery like this:

```
$.post("/Administrator/GetUserData", function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I'm trying to write out the returned data, but the console is showing me Internal Error 500 when I write the code like above...

In other case when returned result is like this:

```
   return Json(new
    {
        Email = user.Email
        // returning just email for example to see in console..
    },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Returning just email as a plain simple string works okay, but when I try to return the User's roles as an array via JSON , then I get problems like above...

The collection UserRoles is of Type ICollection...

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. Guys I dug out the exception, it's like following:

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[MyModel.Models.DatabaseConnection.UserRoles, MyEntity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.

Comment: dont believe you need the `,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` part if its a post

Comment: What is the 500 error you get?

Comment: check the response tab of the ajax  call.

Comment: @JamieD77 thx I'll throw it out, I was abit skeptical about it right away :D

Comment: One sec guys I'll check what's the response

Comment: Guys I posted the exception details

Comment: you need to return a non circular object.. what information do you need from the UsersRole object?

Comment: The ID of the role and RoleName ...

Comment: @JamieD77 Should I just return annonymous type list with specific properties from that collection ?

Comment: yep.. like `Roles = user.UserRoles.Select(a => new {ID = a.ID, RoleName = a.RoleName}).ToList()`

Comment: or you could create a view model and populate/return that instead

Comment: @JamieD77 Okay got it !! Thanks a lot for the quick response =) You wanna post the reply so that I can accept it ?

Comment: @JamieD77 Ye but I figured it's much easier just with annonymous type no ?

Comment: Yeah its easier if it just for display purposes.. a lot of times, my action results like you're using would return a partial view or partial view rendered to html string, so i would need a view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it’s clear that your model of role contains a property point to user which causes the issue.

you should select an anonymous object to return

```
Roles = user.Roles.Select(r=> new { name = r.Name }).ToArray();
```

Comment: This .ToArray() vs ToList() .. Which one is more efficient? =)

Comment: i prefer array in this case, because you just want to return a json, no further action will be taken